# ListView element background color changes to black while scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have a `listview`, when I scroll it, that time listview element background color changes to black. I tried couple of hours, but not getting solution.

I tried

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

or

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case this works fine

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true">
</ListView>
```

One of the developer says, you have to use these 2 properties compulsory..

```
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
```

Answer (score 2):

set the

```
android:cacheColorHint
```

to the color you used as a **background to the ListViewItem**

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
// you can use your color also
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Both color should be same, then your problem will be solved.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add following attributes to your listview inside xml layout.

```
android:scrollingCache="true"
android:cacheColorHint="#ffffff"
```